# How to detect if an alert was shown in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I am using react-native-push-notification and I need to change screens only after a user has made a decision whether or not they want push notifications from my app. But once `onRegister: function(token)` is encountered, a system alert is automatically shown by iOS. How do I listen to the user making a selection on this system alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen to the user's decision.

```
PushNotification.requestPermissions().then((response: any) => {
  if (response && response.alert !== 0) {
    // Allow
    return; 
  }
  // Decline
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not prior experience working with `react-native-push-notification` but have just dig a bit into it and found that it internally uses React Native's [PushNotificationIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios) and that component has the `checkPermissions` method. So it might help you.

Also what you should do is deny the permission once and see if the `token` is available (not null). I believe that the `token`'s availability must be the decision maker for the scenario you are looking for.

Also, Just to let you know, that [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) is a complete package of firebase functionalities and is being maintained well. You should give it a shot if you are starting with the project. The API is similar to official web sdk of firebase with easy to understand doc.